# Autofill input separated by comma or space

Tags: javascript

This my code to autofill input:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("change keyup mouseup", "#tag_content", function(){
     $("#tag_keyword").val($("#tag_content").val());
   });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/javasalden/urxhv486/4/

How to change keyup mouseup to show in 2 input from input paste, separated by comma or space?

Comment: Java and Javascript are no more similar to each other than Car and Carpet.

Comment: @JoeC You're absolutely wrong. Java and JavaScript are relatives. They're both brewed from coffee :-). Oh, and also that when Netscape "created" JavaScript it collaborated with Sun Systems (the owner of Java) and requested it to have similar syntax to Java. So they are related :-) That was back in 1995 though, and the two relatives immigrated to different countries and have never seen each other since :-)

Comment: @RacilHilan Cheers for that.  Clearly I clearly need to find a new simile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're assigning the same ID to two elements. IDs in HTML must be unique.

Secondly, you're assigning the entered value as is without processing. Split it by comma and that will give you an array of two items, so you can assign each of them to the two result boxes.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change keyup mouseup", "#tag_content", function() {
    var longlat = $("#tag_content").val();
    if (longlat) {
      longlat = longlat.split(",");
      $("#tag_keyword_lat").val(longlat[0]);
      if (longlat.length > 1)
        $("#tag_keyword_long").val(longlat[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Data</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="tag_content" id="tag_content" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<div class="dker bg-info form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Latitude</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="tag_keyword" id="tag_keyword_lat" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="dker bg-info form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Long Latitude</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="tag_keyword" id="tag_keyword_long" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>


<br>
<br> if i paste on field data like this -7.972649,112.65860099999998
<br> that data will auto fill on field latitude and long latitude
<br>
<br> like this :
<br> latitude -7.972649
<br> longlatitude 112.65860099999998
<br>

<br>
<br> data separated by coma OR space
```